# Why Does An AJAX Request Have To Have This?

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'script.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                     $("p").text(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

why does an AJAX request have to have a placeholder for the function? (in this case it is 'data'). If you remove it, or use any other word it still works fine. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: This is just Javascript that is built this way. PS AJAX is asynchronous so needs a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` here is **an alias for returned value** (the "answer" for your ajax request to `script.php`), so you can reefer to it. It is NOT the placeholder for function itself.

How you name it is up to you - just like with names of lambda parameters in c++ (I find them similar to JavaScript anonymous functions in that case):

```
[](string data){
   ... = data...
}
```

or with "out" parameters of functions/methods in other languages.

For the C++ analogy: how it would look to pass an lambda as a parameter to another method (you would have to define the `Button` class of course):

```
button.click(/*...,*/ [&](string data){ //"on success"
    MessageBox(NULL, data.c_str(), "Alert", NULL);
    ...
});
```